# Python Logging - get unwanted entries, and how to fix this

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Recently I am trying to learn how to use Python logging module. I set up some custom "info" level logs, but when I look at the results, I see that *Python flask* or *Elasticsearch* also prints some info level logs.

```
==== Start Log: analyze-2024-01-26-14-42-40 ====
01-26 14:42 INFO     GET http://my-es-addr:9210/ [status:200 request:0.164s] -> not what I want
01-26 14:42 INFO     GET http://my-es-addr:9210/ [status:200 request:0.041s] -> not what I want
01-26 14:42 INFO     GET http://my-es-addr:9210/ [status:200 request:0.040s] -> not what I want
01-26 14:42 INFO     [INFO] Found: my-es-addr-9210, ES Name: my-es -> I want this
01-26 14:42 INFO     GET http://my-es-addr:9210/_cat/indices?format=json [status:200 request:0.102s] -> not what I want
01-26 14:42 ERROR    [ES] Instance [cluster1] doesn't exist. -> I want this
```

It looks like Elasticsearch has some reserved info level logs, and I don't have a way to filter them via `setLevel(logging.INFO)` because I also want my logs to be output at the INFO level.

my code looks like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                                    filename=log_file_path,
                                    filemode='a+',
                                    level=logging.INFO)

# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stder
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-3s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger().addHandler(console)
logger = logging.getLogger("analyzer")

logger.info("xxxxxx")
```

Is there any approach to print my "info"-level logs only, instead of all logs?